# Do the DRESS vowel (/e/) and SQUARE vowel (/ɛː/) have the same vowel quality in contemporary RP?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, phonetics, received-pronunciation

I understand that the SQUARE vowel is now often realized as the long monophthong /ɛː/ instead of the traditional diphthong /eə/ in contemporary RP. Do /e/ from the DRESS vowel and /ɛː/ from the modern realization of the SQUARE vowel share the same vowel quality then, differing only in vowel length?

Comment: This might be better for [Linguistics.SE].

Comment: Different people pronounce vowels differently. Maybe they're exactly the same, or maybe they're slightly different. In many dialects, they're certainly not different enough to be reliably distinguished without using the length (but for some English dialects, that's also true of *lark* and *luck*).